# How to invert coordinate frames of a Transform

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ar-track-alvar, ar-kinect, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a fixed transform coming from the [ar_track_alvar](http://wiki.ros.org/ar_track_alvar) pkg, that gives me the markers pose into the camera_link. I want to get the inverse of it and save the exact data but reversed. The problem is that being the marker frame reversed, the inverse gives me wrong result.

How to have x and y markers coordinates to be consistent with the camera_link ones? What is the easiest way to achieve this?
I want to have x pointing forward (red) and y on the left (green).

[image: image description]

Thanks for anyone helping me out!

Cheers,
Simone.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283860/how-to-invert-coordinate-frames-of-a-transform/) by [simff](https://answers.ros.org/users/31951/simff/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2018-02-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tuandl](https://answers.ros.org/users/28760/tuandl/) on 2018-02-27**:
Since you already have a transform from your markers to camera_link, have you tried to apply a rotation with respect to camera_link in your marker's frame?

**Comment by [simff](https://answers.ros.org/users/31951/simff/) on 2018-02-27**:
Hi @tuandl thanks for the comment! Not yet, I do not know the way to code it, I am new to ROS and tf, How would you to that? Can you append here a simple code snippet or code steps I have to take?
I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a [basic tf tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28C%2B%2B%29)
You want to do something like

```
try{
      listener.lookupTransform("camera_link", "ar_marker",ros::Time(0), transform);
    }
```

Follow the tutorial to get the marker's positions.

---

Originally posted by [tuandl](https://answers.ros.org/users/28760/tuandl/) with karma: 358 on 2018-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0